# The 2 lowest numbers of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

The question is simple (the answer too probably) :
How can I find the 2 lowest numbers of an array?

```
  for ( i = 1; i <= n ; i++){
        if(v[i] < maxim)
        maxim = v[i];
                            }
  cout << maxim;
```

this is the only thing that comes to mind to me but it only shows me the lowest number, not the 2 lowest numbers

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/to-find-smallest-and-second-smallest-element-in-an-array/

Comment: The easy approach is to sort the array and then can access the lowest `n` items fairly easy. You could also introduce an extra variable to store the 2nd lowest number.

Comment: sorting the array takes kinda lot of line codes and how could i introduce a second variable

Comment: Calling `std::sort` can be done in a single line, so that is even less code :) http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/NhA0RXSz/ That second variable is exactly what @KamleshArya has proposed with his link (see the comment above).

Comment: Note that C/C++ arrays are 0-index based, So your loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)`.

Comment: @martijnn2008: `std::nth_element` is also a single line and is asymptotically optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another simple way would be..

```
int v[] = {33,11,22,3};
int secmaxim = INT_MAX-1;
int maxim = INT_MAX;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++){
        if(v[i] < maxim)
        {
             secmaxim = maxim;
             maxim = v[i];
        }
    else if(v[i] < secmaxim && v[i] != maxim)
            secmaxim = v[i];
 }
  cout << maxim << secmaxim;
```

Comment: brilliant! easy and logical

Comment: @griffinwish: This method is also faster than sorting. As a beginner you may not care about that yet, but in time you will.

Comment: @Beta You should only chose the fastest possible (over readable, simple and reusable) code when it is appropriate, and not earlier. As a beginner you may not care about that yet, but in time you will.

Comment: Also, this code is wrong and incomplete. Array indices are off by one, and no initialization for the two introduced variables is shown.

Comment: I think in initial level one should try to improve his problem solving skills... We discussed here two ways to solve this problem... you can still find other ways to solve this problem .. :-)..

Comment: At a guess, I'd say the downvote had something to do with resentment of your answer being accepted over someone else's.

Comment: And in case of duplicate, your result may be strange.

Answer (score 4):

If your array may be changed, you can use [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort):

```
std::partial_sort(v, v+2, v+n);
```

Then, `v[0]` and `v[1]` are the two smallest values of `v`.

If changing the array is not intended, or should be avoided, [`std::partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) is your friend. Introduce a new array of two elements into which the minima should be written:

```
int minima[2];
std::partial_sort_copy(v, v+n, minima, minima+2);
```

(Please change the type of the array `minima` accordingly. I don't know the type of your array `v`.)

To make these functions available, you have to include the following file:

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Comment: I am not familiar with what std:: means and not even familiar with that (function?) partial_sort_copy

Comment: use "using namespace std;" after header, if you don't want to using std:: .

Comment: Yes it is a function. `std::` means, that it is part of the C++ standard library, which has a lot of useful building blocks.

Comment: @griffinwish wouldn't it better if you start with basics like `hello world`?

Comment: @martijnn2008 Nope. STL is the predecessor of what is now *part* of the standard library. It is the name of a different library.

Comment: I'm just wondering why people don't use using namespace std instead of writing std:: all over

Comment: Because when you have indentically named symbols in your codebase, or in other libraries which namespaces you're pulling in with `using namespace`, you have ambiguities. For example, if you use another library which has a function `sort`, and you `#include <algorithm>`, and then write `using namespace ...`, then you can't use the `sort` function at all. This problem is solved with introducing namespaces in the first place, and writing `using namespace` kinda undoes this.

Comment: `std::nth_element` is more appropriate (and faster) for this question.

Answer (score 2):

How to find the `k` smallest elements of an array in C++.

Naive method: Call `std::sort`; look at first `k` elements. Running time O(n log n).

Interview question method: Loop through array, using a `std::set` (or `std::push_heap` and `pop_heap`) with `k` elements to keep track of the lowest `k`. Running time O(n log k). Also does not modify the array, returns the results in order, and only uses O(k) additional space.

Best method: `#include <algorithm>`. `std::nth_element(&a[0], &a[k], &a[n])`. Look at first `k` elements. Running time O(n), which is optimal.

[Update]

I feel like I should explain what I mean by "interview question method". If you are actually asked this question in an interview, you are probably at Google or Amazon or some other big-data-yadda-yadda environment, and the interviewer said something like, "I have 100 billion integers on disk and I want to know the smallest 1000 of them." In that context, solutions that modify the array or that require O(n) additional space are probably not the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use std::sort() to sort the elements

Here is a small example to display how sort works?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> arr {5,3,24,9,7};

    std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());

    std::cout << arr[0] << std::endl << arr[1];

    return 0;
}
```

In code above, `std::sort` will sort the array `arr` in ascending order. `<algorithm>` is header is required for using `sort`.

The output would be

> 3
>
> 5

[Here](https://ideone.com/0FJRfA) is link to the working version of code above.

Comment: This is unnecessarily inefficient.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Agreed that its `O(n log(n))` but OP didn't ask for fastest so I posted an alternate solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the order of the array,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> v {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4};

    int smallest        = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    int second_smallest = *std::min_element(v.begin(), v.end(), [&smallest](int i, int j) { return i < j && i >= smallest; });

    std::cout << "smallest: "        << smallest        << std::endl;
    std::cout << "second smallest: " << second_smallest << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
smallest: 1
second smallest: 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Adapted from @leemes answer (using more modern syntax), see his answer for an explanation.

```
const auto topVals = 2;
std::array<int, topVals> minima;

std::partial_sort_copy(std::begin(v), std::end(v), minima.begin(), minima.end());
```

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: I know... it would have been a comment to @leemes answer, but I don't have enough reputation....

Comment: That doesn't matter. It doesn't change the fact that this isn't ananswer.

Comment: Again, `std::nth_element` is more appropriate (and faster) for this question.

Comment: Well, ok for a value of 2 it probably is, but it is not very extensible. If he later changes it to get the top 3 in order, then it won't work, as you are not guaranteed that the order of the first 2 elements (of the 3) is correct. For instance: 3, 2, 1, might end up as 2, 1, 3, it only correctly places the nth_element (in this case the 3rd one). Also what if he doesn't want to modify the original array?

Comment: @WesleyShillingford: (a) He did not say the result had to be in order. (b) If you cannot modify the original array and want the results in order, you should use a set or binary heap that only requires O(k) additional space. (See my answer.) In short, this answer is inferior regardless of your assumptions.

Comment: @Nemo Questionable about the performance, seems it may be implementation defined, as nth_element ends up sorting the whole container from the few tests I did on VC12 (using default settings), while partial_sort doesn't.

Comment: @WesleyShillingford: Kudos for actually trying it. But if you are right that VC12 sorts the elements, then that is a bug in VC12, because this is absolutely not implementation-defined. The [C++ language specification section 25.3.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/lib-algorithms.html#lib.alg.nth.element) requires the complexity of `nth_element` to be "linear on average". This has been true since C++98.